# How to solve "clean exit" nodemon problem?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, nodemon

I'm trying to run a server on my local.
I've created a user in the database, installed the npm dependencies and when I am trying to run it, I'm getting this: `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`.

I'm cloning this repo: https://github.com/Ninad99/jwt-node-graphql

What may cause the problem?

Comment: It is not a problem. nodemon watches the file to detect any change. If there is a change in file, it auto restart server. Through this one does not need to re-run the server again and again

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that repo was outdated. So simple `npm update` resolved issue :)